# Errors when checking eligibility for HSTS preload

Tags: http, https, hsts

I have this website set up:
http://website1.com/ - returns `301 Moved Permanently` and redirects to http://www.website1.com/.

http://www.website1.com/ - returns `301 Moved Permanently` and redirects to https://www.website2.com/.

https://www.website2.com/ - returns `200 OK` and has this in the response:

`strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains`

I have this subdomain running a web app:
https://subdomain.website1.com/
This also has the following header in the response:

`Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains`

I want to have preload functionality for all sub domains of website1.com/.
However, I get the following errors when checking [eligibility](https://hstspreload.org/):

```
Error: No HSTS header
Response error: No HSTS header is present on the response.

Error: HTTP redirects to www first
http://website1.com (HTTP) should immediately redirect to https://website1.com (HTTPS) before adding the www subdomain.
Right now, the first redirect is to http://www.website1.com/.
The extra redirect is required to ensure that any browser which supports HSTS will record the HSTS entry for the top level domain, not just the subdomain.
```

The first error is easy, I can just add the HSTS header.

But why does it matter that there's a redirect?

All I want is for http://subdomain.website1.com/ to make an internal redirect to https://subdomain.website1.com/, and for http://website1.com/ to internally redirect to https://website1.com/.

Can't http://website1.com make an internal redirect to https://website1.com, regardless of the fact that it redirects to [www.website1.com/](http://www.website1.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this website set up: http://website1.com/ - returns 301 Moved Permanently and redirects to http://www.website1.com/.

This is your issue. http://website1.com should redirect to https://website1.com then on to https://www.website1.com.

This way the top level website1.com domain will pick up the HSTS header and protect itself and all sub domains (assuming it has `includeSubDomains` attribute set - which is a pre-requisite for preloading).

Without switching to HTTPS first, or if you skip straight to https://www.website1.com then the browser will never see the HSTS header on the top level domain and so know that it (and all sub domains) should be protected by HSTS. This is 1) less secure and 2) more risky when preloading as maybe you still have a non-HTTPS site (e.g. http://blog.website1.com or http://intranet.website1.com). By forcing you to set this up before you preload it, will hopefully surface those issues, when it’s still possible to reverse HSTS (which is basically impossible after its preloaded into browser’s source code - at least for many months anyway).

And the risk of accidentally locking out a non-HTTPS subdomain with preload is one reason [I’ve argued in the past that preload is potentially more risky than useful](https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/dangerous-web-security-features/), and overkill for most sites. But with HTTPS becoming the norm, I’m less against it now. Still think it’s a bit overkill except for high target sites though.

Btw for the first error, make sure HSTS header is included on 301 redirects. For Apache for example you need `always set` rather than just `set` as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103216/2144578

Comment: You didn't finish your sentence:
" But with HTTPS becoming the norm I’m"

Comment: Oops. Finished now.

Comment: Does the preload feature make the HSTS header redundant? If Chrome knows to use HTTPS instead of HTTP because of preload, then the HSTS header isn't really doing anything right?

Comment: "Btw for the first error, make sure HSTS header is included on 301 redirects." - But those redirects are using http. You're not meant to return HSTS when using http.

Comment: It’s not redundant for two important reasons: 1) Not every browser supports the preload list. Does GoogleBot for example? Do you not care if your web page is found in search for example? 2) The preload list will check for presence of the header and may remove it from the preload list of you remove it. So yes for browsers that support preload it’s not really doing anything, but what’s the reason to not send it? To save a measly few bytes?

Comment: You should redirect from http website1.com to https website1.com to https www.website1.com. The first redirect does not need HSTS header as not over https, but second redirect is over https and should have HSTS header. The whole point of that double redirect so to enable the browser to pick up the HSTS header for the base domain.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Do you know why you can't preload just a single subdomain? Not including subdomains is a potential security risk, as any subdomain will get all of the top-level domain's cookies, but I would have thought the opposite would be fine, ie. preloading a subdomain but not the domain.

Comment: I’d guess if you’re not ready to preload the whole domain, there’s a question if you’re really ready for preload at all! Or in need of preload since you don’t think HTTPS is important enough to have on all sub domains.

Comment: I emailed and asked. They said it's because the list is hardcoded in browsers, and if they let single subdomains be preloaded, the list would be massive.

Comment: Are you able to help with this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235265/whats-the-point-of-access-control-allow-credentials