# What's the point of Access-Control-Allow-Credentials?

Tags: http, cors, csrf, same-origin-policy

The default value for sending cookies is `SameSite=Lax`, which means cookies are sent for GET requests, but blocked for POST.

With a cross origin GET request, the response is blocked anwyay due to the `Same-Origin-Policy`, unless the response contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Why isn't `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` enough?

Why would you ever want to return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: someDomain.com` without also returning `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`?

Why allow a cross origin GET request from a trusted domain, but block the response only if the cookie was sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allowing cross-origin sharing is much riskier in the presence of cookies, since that's what can reveal a user's private information to a malicious script. Without cookies, the script can only access public information—the same information that could be accessed by just navigating to the URL from any computer.

So the existence of the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` marks an important security inflection point, and usefully distinguishes between sharing public and private information.

For example, let's say you have an API that's distributing stock ticker data and you want to allow scripts from other sites to access this API. CORS is necessary since the Same Origin Policy will otherwise prevent those scripts from seeing the data. There's no need for cookies, though. So the site can simply use `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and be done. There's no risk of sharing any private data.

By contrast, a site that wants to enable the sharing of user-specific data will have to opt-in by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`. Moreover, the site is forced to specify the specific sites allowed, since `*` is not valid for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in this case.

Comment: It still seems redundant though.
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials marks an important security inflection point, and usefully distinguishes between sharing public and private information"- 
Why isn't `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: someDomain.com` enough to distinguish this?
If public information is shared, `*` would be used. If private information is shared, then someDomain.com is used.
I still can't think of a situation where you'd want `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: someDomain.com` but no `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. If you don't want the cookie being sent then why not just use `*`?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: You might want to share your information (i.e. enable other people to create web apps with your data) only with certain sites, for business reasons. That doesn't mean you want to share private data with them.

Comment: In that situation, couldn't any random web app still use your API, even though you're returning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin onlyOneDomain.com`? They would just have to make the call on the backend, instead of the front-end. From the backend, you can easily put whatever you want for the Origin header can't you?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: Sure, that's possible. But the fact that it's possible to work around a protocol feature doesn't make it redundant. In my opinion, these two headers represent two distinct concepts (*what sites do I share with?* and *do I share private information*?), and conflating them would be confusing and would eliminate some use cases, with no real benefit.